# "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'oracledb-for-lambda'" when trying to connect oracledb to lambda function using layer?

Tags: node.js, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to connect my lambda function (node.js) to oracle database. For that, I've decided to use the npm library 'oracledb-for-lambda'.

The steps Ive followed:

1.Created parent folder in system and `npm init` inside.

2.`npm i --save oracledb-for-lambda`

3.created nodejs folder and moved node_modules inside

4.Moved libociei.so from \nodejs\node_modules\oracledb-for-lambda\lib to lib folder

[Now, I think I am supposed to COPY this file and not move it BUT this file is over 100mb and so the parent directory becomes ~300mb before zipping which is impossible to use in a Lambda Layer]

This is my folder structure:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMuOg.png

5.Zipped the parent folder and created an s3 bucket and uploaded this file.

6.Create a layer in Lambda and pasted the URL of the zip file from s3

7.Add this custom layer

In Lambda Code:

```
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
var oracledb = require('oracledb-for-lambda');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    let str_host = os.hostname() + ' localhost\n';
    fs.writeFileSync(process.env.HOSTALIASES, str_host, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    var connAttr = {
        user: process.env.USERNAME,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        connectString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING
    };
    
    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        oracledb.getConnection(connAttr, function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                reject({
                    status: "ERROR"
                });
            }
            resolve({
                status: "SUCCESS"
            });
        });
    });
    return promise;  
}
```

In Lambda Configuration:

Environment variables (4)

CONNECTION_STRING   //ip:port/xyz

HOSTALIASES /tmp/HOSTALIASES

PASSWORD    password

USERNAME    username

8.Then I saved and deployed this function.

In API gateway, Ive connected this lambda function through lambda proxy integration which I deploy and get this message:

> {"message": "Internal server error"}

When I go to CloudWatch Logs I can see this:

```
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'oracledb-for-lambda'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'oracledb-for-lambda'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/index.js",
        "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.js",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:202:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Search stackoverflow for similar questions